# git web backend not allowing me to browse git projects

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, git

I am running a git server on CentOS 7.  The apache we server is running on port 88 and I am able to clone and update my files through the cli using http on port 88.  So the server itself is listening and functioning on port 88.  The problem I have is that when I try to browse to it I am unable to view the files via a browser.   I have also fixed the selinux stuff to work correctly, so this is not the issue.

The error I keep getting is :
[Mon Oct 26 10:52:04.976770 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 877] [client 10.4.79.31:51279] AH01215: Request not supported: '/var/www/git/'

```
<VirtualHost *:88>
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
DocumentRoot /var/www/git
ScriptAlias / /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/

<Directory "/usr/libexec/git-core">
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/git">
Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What you're using is `git-htttp-backend`, which is the Git server implementation (that is, the service that Git talks to to upload and download data).  If you want to have an HTML-based UI, you need gitweb (or something else, like cgit).

Comment: Any solutions yet?